# node printer.node is not a valid win32 application

Tags: node.js, angular, windows

I have developed a node API for my angular application, My node application uses node-printer package for printing pdf files generated by node, when i tried to run my application using nodemon i am getting an error

> node printer.node is not a valid win32 application

The same application is working on the other machine without any error. both the machines are of X64 bit architecture.

also i have also tried to install node js 32 bit then too i am getting same error.

Comment: share your code

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This worked for me, installing printer as such:

```
npm install printer --build-from-source
```

Comment: This works for me (node 12.x.x & printer (tojocky/node-printer 0.4.0)

Answer (score 0):

After so many attempts i have deleted **`node_modules`** folder from an application and fire an **npm install** command to add all modules again that resolves the problem.

Comment: Not really a solution

Answer (score 0):

Hi there let me go through what's happened on my site here in 2022.

So if you're going to use `npm install printer` for your Electron application, you're using a native module as deemed by electron.

Since Electron has a different application binary interface (ABI) from a given Node.js binary that you used to install your printer . Therefore, we need to rebuild the native module (in this case printer) for Electron.

For more detail check [this](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/using-native-node-modules) out.

1. First, install electron-rebuild for your project. `npm i electron-rebuild`.
2. Second, install a native module using e.g. `npm i printer`
3. Third, after installed native module, execute `./node_modules/.bin/electron-rebuild` to rebuild the native module.

Comment: Delete node_modules and reinstall won't get rid of the problem.